BigQuery system variables - values for current statement in a multi-statement job
My BigQuery procedural SQL script contains a loop, where each iteration deletes some records from a table.  I want to save some stats for each iteration of the loop by inserting system-variable values into another table:
insert into dsname.log_table (run_dt, rows_deleted, bytes_processed, bytes_billed, slot_ms) 
select current_timestamp(), @@row_count, @@script.bytes_processed, @@script.bytes_billed, @@script.slot_ms;

I find that the bytes_processed, bytes_billed and slot_ms values are cumulative - that is, the number of bytes processed, etc so far in the multi-statement job.
I'd like to instead save the number of bytes processed for the specific statement executed rather than that cumulative value - that is the difference between @@script.bytes_processed and the last value saved.
How can I best achieve that?
